# How to assign a background image to the Atom.io editor?

Tags: less, atom-editor

I have a background image that a friend (digitaly) painted for me. It is a stunning piece of art and I would like to set it as the background of my Editor.

However... which selector do I use in my LESS file? I found out that using `.pane` targets the editor view, `.tree-view` the left-hand sidebar. But how do I set the wallpaper across all of them?

My first idea was to first remove the background of `.editor` and `.tree-view`...but which selector do I then use to load my background image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a package called [`editor-background`](https://atom.io/packages/editor-background) which not only allows you to set a background, but even a background video:

[image: Screenshot of Editor Background Package]

You can install it by opening the settings view with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd> switching to the `Install` panel and searching for `editor-background`.  You can also install from the command line by running:

```
apm install editor-background
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, thank you for taking the time to answer some of the older questions in the [atom-editor] tag.  Please take a few minutes to read over ["How to write a good answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider the edits I have made to you're answers over the last hour, we strongly encourage the highest possible quality of answer.  In addition please read over the question very carefully, in this instance your answer didn't meet all of the requirements from the OP and will likely be subject to downvotes.